# Reading columns of data from a file that adds or removes columns

Tags: python, file-read

I am trying to adjust my python program to be "adaptable" to files with more or less columns of data.
The current method I have is this:

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/gwong/Documents/ME 021/CylindricalRollerBearingData_01.txt'

answer = 'y'
col0 = []
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
col4 = []
col5 = []
col6 = []
col7 = []
col8 = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as DataFile:
    Title = DataFile.readline()
    header = DataFile.readline().split()
    units = DataFile.readline().split()
    for line in DataFile:
        valstrings = line.split()
        col0.append(float(valstrings[0]))
        col1.append(float(valstrings[1]))
        col2.append(float(valstrings[2]))
        col3.append(float(valstrings[3]))
        col4.append(float(valstrings[4]))
        col5.append(float(valstrings[5]))
        col6.append(float(valstrings[6]))
        col7.append(float(valstrings[7]))
        col8.append(valstrings[8] + valstrings[9])
```

The data file looks like this:

```
SKF Bearing Data for Cylindrical roller bearings, single row (Metric)
Principal dimensions    Basic load ratings  Fatigue load limit  Speed ratings   Designation
d[mm]   D[mm]   B[mm]   C[kN]   C0[kN]  Pu[kN]  Ref speed[r/min]    Lim speed[r/min]    Designation bearing
15  35  11  12.5    10.2    1.22    22000   26000   NJ 202 ECP
15  35  11  12.5    10.2    1.22    22000   26000   NU 202 ECP
15  35  11  12.5    10.2    1.22    22000   34000   NU 202 ECPHA
```

This is how the code the data from the file is being used:

```
while (answer == 'y'):
    UserMins =[] 
    UserMaxs =[]
    ans = 'y'
    while (ans == 'y'):
        UserVals = []


        UserVals.append(col0)
        UserVals.append(col1)
        UserVals.append(col2)
        UserVals.append(col3)
        UserVals.append(col4)
        UserVals.append(col5)
        UserVals.append(col6)
        UserVals.append(col7)
```

While this is inefficient, this works for the current file I am using. However, If I were change the file with another one with different columns, it will bring up and error that the list is out of range or it will not print all the data in the file.

Is there a possible way to read data from a file no matter the amount of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `col0` through `col8` as individuals lists, you could have a list of lists where `cols = [[]]`. You have the block

```
for line in DataFile:
        valstrings = line.split()
        col0.append(float(valstrings[0]))
        col1.append(float(valstrings[1]))
        ...
```

which is a naive approach to dealing with each element in `valstrings`. Another for loop could be added inside the `for line in DataFile:` loop that inserts each column value into the appropriate array.

```
for line in DataFile:
        valstrings = line.split()
        for i,val in enumerate(valstrings):
                 cols[i].append(float(val))
```

I'm not exactly sure how the section with `UserVals.append(col0)` etc. is being used, but I would try to use the column headings as keys in a dictionary so you can reference each column without knowing how many there are, and it should make your code a bit more readable.

The first block of code could certainly be cleaned up to look like:

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/gwong/Documents/ME 021/CylindricalRollerBearingData_01.txt'

answer = 'y'
# Note that cols starts as a list, and lists are appended to it later
cols = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as DataFile:
    Title = DataFile.readline()
    header = DataFile.readline().split()
    units = DataFile.readline().split()
    for line in DataFile:
        valstrings = line.split()
        # Edit made here to initialize cols list of lists
        for col in valstrings:
            cols.append([])
        for i,val in enumerate(valstrings):
                 cols[i].append(float(val))
```

And I think the bottom section could be changed to:

```
while (answer == 'y'):
    UserMins =[] 
    UserMaxs =[]
    ans = 'y'
    while (ans == 'y'):
        UserVals = []
        for col in cols:
            UserVals.append(col)
```

I haven't tested it, but you may have to initialize the elements of the `cols` array to empty lists before you start referencing `cols[i]`

Comment: It's currently returning:
'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: I edited the code to address this. At the bottom I mentioned you may have to initialize each of the columns in the `cols` array, so I added that loop after `valstrings` is made.